# preg_replace to remove multiple matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have looked around but couldn't find an appropiate solution.

I have this string

```
$area = array("Some Text area 1", "Some Text area 2", "Some Text area 33", "Some Text area 40")
```

I want to construct a preg_replace that would remove the word "area" and the 1 or 2 digit number that follows.

I can do this to remove "area 1"

```
$area = preg_replace('/area 1/','', $area);
```

I can keep repeating this to remove other matches but it's not very efficiant.

Can I remove the pattern with just one preg_replace?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$area = preg_replace('/area [0-9]+/','', $area);
```

Will remove all matches which have the text 'area' followed by a number.

Answer (score 1):

Specify atleast one digit with:
`preg_replace('/area [0-9]+/','', $area);`

Answer (score 1):

Do you also want to remove the space right before the word "area"? The code for that would be:

```
$area = preg_replace('/ area \d+/', '', $area);
```

Comment: Don't need to remove the space, but good to know anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post while searching for something similar: replace multiple terms in a text string.

So, for example I was making a automatically generated drop down select, and the options were based on filenames and I needed to load the filenames and generate a human readable filename as well.

My files were named: temp_Event_Name.php

So I had to remove the "temp", "_", and the ".php" so that there would be a selectable option, the value would be the filename to be passed onto a subsequent form which would use the file to generate a PDF.

```
<select>
 <option value="temp_Event_Name_2011.php">Event 1</option>
 <option value="temp_Event_Name_2012.php">Event 2</option>
</select
```

What I found was to use `str_replace`.

So the full code would be:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $files as $d ){
    $file_and_name .= '<option value="'.$files[$i].'">'.str_replace('temp','',str_replace('_',' ',str_replace('.php','',$d) ) )."</option>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Where
$files is an array with the filenames, which I obtained through:

```
$files = array();
$files = glob("temp_*.php");
```

Obviously extra formatting is needed to get it into the html I've proposed, but that's easy. Hope it helps @jamester or anyone else who comes across this.